# Any possibility for life on moons of planets in our Solar System

Tags: the-moon, solar-system, planet, life

We all focused on our moon, to find water or life, or any thing related to life. But my question is, is there any chance for life in moons of other planets in our solar system, others have too many moons....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you check 2001 A Space Odyssey saga, Europa is actually a satellite with Life.

Coming back to real space, the "comfort zone" for life is approximately from Venus' orbit to Mars' orbit. There, only Moon, Phobos and Deimos are satellites, and all of them are too dry to have any kind of life.

Beyond the comfort zone you need some other way for water not to frozen (a commonly referred prerequisite of Life), so you'll need a volcanic or tidal-heatened satellite. There are a few of these. Europa and Io come to my mind just now. Life there could be possible.

Comment: Is any expiriments done for finding life in europa or lo.., i don't heard about it..

Comment: I do not remember any specific mission for that.

Comment: i think the 'comfort zone' differ for each type of living things, so there may be chance of life in other areas in our solar system. am I right.

Comment: 'comfort zone' is not defined as the zone where a specific living species will be comfortable, but as the zone where Life as we know it is possible in a planetary body. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comfort_zone_(astronomy)